# Convert string into a valid JSON in c#

Tags: c#, json.net

In the code snippet below, the JSON string in the commented out `jsonString` variable is valid while the uncommented out one causes `JObject.Parse` to throw a `JsonReaderException` with the message:
`After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: e. Path 'Key', line 1, position 15.`

```
    var jsonString = "{\"Key\":\"Value \"extra\" \"}";
    //var jsonString = "{\"Key\":\"Value \\\"extra\\\" \"}";

    JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

Are there any methods available in Newtonsoft.Json or elsewhere that can transform a JSON string to make it valid?

Comment: How do you have this broken JSON in the first place?

Comment: The reason why you get an error is because the parser cannot match opening and closing quotes in your uncommented value. So, `\"` is parsed as `"` and if you apply this to your string you will end up with following parsed string: `{"Key":"Value "extra" "}`. Now look at this parsed string and ask your self if its possible to clearly identify opening and closing quotes for the value part of Key and the answer is no. That is why you get an error.  In your commented string, the parser can easily identify opening and closing quotes after parsing and hence it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

No, because NewtonSoft cannot guess what you want. E.g. is extra a new key and did you just ommit a comma or is it part of the previous value, or is it just something that can be ignored. It would be better to have the thing you are consuming the json from construct valid json.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex might help you to resolve the existing JSON you have. If you can control how subsequent JSON is generated, you really should fix it at that point.

This solution counts the value as existing from the first " after `a` `"key":`, through to the last `"` before a `,` or a `}`, and then it reserializes the value to ensure that it is correctly escaped. If it finds `",`, it expects it to be followed by another key (`"key":`). This is in an attempt to avoid red herrings (i.e. `{"key": "test "," value"}`) which might otherwise confuse it.

```
private static string FixJson(string json)
{
    var regex = new Regex("\"(?<key>.*?)\"\\W?:\\W?\"(?<value>.*?)\"(?=,\".*?\"\\W?:|}$)");
    return regex.Replace(json, new MatchEvaluator(m => {
        var key = m.Groups["key"].Value;
        var val = m.Groups["value"].Value;
        return string.Format("\"{0}\":{1}", key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(val));
    }));
}
```

Disclaimer: It's a regular expression, it's not foolproof, and if your JSON is more broken than you have indicated, it will probably spit out broken JSON, or incorrect values, so use it at your own risk.

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/IIO95768)